# Replace values within Request.Form using linq

Tags: forms, model-view-controller, replace, asp.net-mvc-5

On my view I have a dropdown, its name is ColorProperty1

When we submit to the controller I'm trying to use linq to find the name in Request.Form and replace the value

as shown here

```
 var Id = (from f in Request.Form.Cast<string>().Where(s => s.StartsWith("ColorProperty")).Select(a => a.Replace("ColorProperty", string.Empty)));
```

And yes the value I'm after is the number 1, I know I could change the name to be 1 but unfortunately I don't have control over the name, the above linq statement is complaining it saying

"group, clause or select clause expected"

We can do this using the following

```
foreach (string item in Request.Form)
{
    if (item.StartsWith("ColorProperty"))
       {
          model.ColorProperty = item.Replace("ColorProperty", string.Empty);
       }
}
```

But Ideally I would like to do it Linq, is it possible? if so can someone correct my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get the solution

```
string colorId = Request.Form.Cast<string>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.StartsWith("ColorProperty")).Replace("ColorProperty", string.Empty);
```